# How to immediately show group answers onscreen?

Tags: lecturer, answering-questions, technology

I teach at a university, and during lectures I would like to pose a question to all the students in which each student types their answer into their laptop, submits to me, and I can show all the answers on my screen at the front of the room. I will be able to see the names on my computer, but on the shared screen the students will not be able to. Is there any technology that does this?

Comment: Kahoot might have this functionality. And it's fun!

Answer (score 3):

We have the Moodle online teaching tool, another is Blackboard.

On moodle one of the possible activities is "feedback" where you set the questions and make it anonymous as you wish... This may meet what you are looking for.

This does mean that all the students must get a moodle account etc.

I have seen other sites that do this interactive survey type activity but can't think of their names off-hand, but they still need the students to log-in...

A quick google search gave this article : https://www.educatorstechnology.com/2018/09/some-of-best-tools-for-creating-surveys.html

The first 4 of their list (as links can fail) Google-forms, Plickers, Kahoot and Socrative...

I use the quiz activity on moodle a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I use http://www.arsnova.eu in my lectures. It won't show the names of individual students, but otherwise I find it a useful way to keep students engaged in a large lecture.

I don't miss that I don't see the individual names, as I use it to encourage students to actively interact with the material during the lecture. So students making mistakes is not a problem; as long as they try, then I am happy. The fact that students know that any mistake they make cannot have a consequence is actually helpful in overcoming any inhibition they may have. But this obviously depends on how you intend to use this tool.